# can't use RDP client with VPN on

Tags: debian, networking, vpn, route, remmina

As soon as I turn on my corporate VPN, `remmina` looses connection (`rdp` protocol to a host **outside** of VPN).
Similarly, as soon as I turn off `tap0` connection created by VPN, `remmina` starts working again.

I d rather have both, how I can achieve that?

I am on:

```
denis@debian:~$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

remmina version: 1.3.3

I do not have access to VPN server, it's a corporate environnement so I won't be able to modify any settings there. I am not sure I should dump all `route` information here?..

Some information on VPN (OpenVPN):

```
vpn.service-type:                       org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        wlo1
VPN.CFG[7]:                             dev = tap0


openvpn config file:
client
dev tap0
proto udp
remote-cert-tls server
remote ******
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-128-CBC-SHA
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
comp-lzo
pull
setenv PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/scripts/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre
```

Comment: Any explanation on why downvote?

Comment: What VPN implementation and protocol are you using?

Comment: I have edited question with more information

Comment: Your configuration is pulling all routes from the VPN Server (keyword `pull`). I suggest you take a look at the routes after the VPN has established and see whether they're pushing a new route that's effectively your new default. Remove or replace that one

Comment: Don't mind the downvotes. Lots of trigger-happy people who like to downvote interesting questions and valid answers.

Comment: @roaima oh, so you re telling me because VPN establishes a default route, the RDP traffic is sent down to that default route too? so I just need to handle the remote RDP host independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, thanks to @roaima comment, it was easy to fix actually.
Noting this for my future self:

```
sudo ip route add <remote-rdp-host> via 192.168.1.1
```

192.168.1.1 being my `default` gateway when no VPN is up.
You can use `traceroute <host>` to know which gateway is taken (or `ip route get ...`)

Another way is to delete `default <vpn ip>` so that it's not used by default for all traffic. In that case, adding explicit rule for `<remote-rdp-host>` isn't needed